# How to set up a listener for form.set_data event in Symfony 2?

Tags: events, symfony, listener

Seems like a pretty simple problem but I've been trying for a while and can't get it to work. I need to hook into the form.set_data event in Symfony 2 in order to modify the data being set in the form from an existing DB record.

I'm trying the following:

Config.yml:

```
services:
    Acme.DemoBundle.listener.set_data:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\RequestListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: form.set_data, method: onFormSetData }
```

RequestListener.php

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle;
...
class RequestListener {
    public function onFormSetData(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        echo 'Eureka!'; die();
    }
}
```

I never get the `echo` or `die`. I am sure that the event is being dispatched (fired). I verified that using debugging (xDebug). Looks like the listener is not being registered.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you have to use your `FormBuilder` instance's dispatcher for all form.* events.

```
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EventListener\MyListener;

function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
  $listener = new MyListener();
  $builder
    ->addEventListener('event', array($listener, 'method'), priority);
}
```

I used the `addEventListener` since the [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html) only mentions `addEventSubscriber`.

If you need to have an event added for all forms, you can create an extension:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EventListener\MyListener;

class FormTypeMyExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
  public function getExtendedType()
  {
    return 'form';
  }

  public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
  {
    $listener = new MyListener();
    $builder->addEventListener('event', array($listener, 'method'));
  }
}
```

And register the extension as a service:

```
services:
    acme_demo.form.extension.myextension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension\MyExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, alias: form }
```

For more, see the [Symfony API](http://api.symfony.com).